# Is there a way to save run results and show those run results before running all tests?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm very new to jasmine and currently using the standalone version. I was wondering if there is a way to save the run results and show the results on the spec runner before running through all tests?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To put it into simpler words, I was asking if there was a way to save the results after a run is done and show the previous results from that run before running through all the tests.

Comment: Currently, when I run the jasmine standalone, it just runs through all the tests and shows the results from that run.